# Redirect after successful registration

Tags: javascript, php

I have a registration wherein if successful it would redirect to a certain page.
I'm having problem when a successful registration happens it would redirect to successReg.php my registration has a link that myurl/mobile/registration.php it should redirect to myurl/successReg.php instead what happens is it redirects to myurl/mobile/successReg.php which doesn't exist. So how can I make it to redirect at myurl/successReg.php?

Here is how I redirect when the registration is a success.

```
   echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>            

   window.location.href='successReg.php';
          </SCRIPT>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you specified a relative path. If your document root is myurl/ then Ben's solution is just fine, otherwise you should give the full path from your document root (like myurl/successReg.php).

If you want to accomplish this with javascript you can do:

```js
window.location = '/successReg.php';
```

If you redirect with javascript without the starting / it's always relative to the current uri, so in you case it redirects to myurl/mobile/successReg.php if you are redirecting from myurl/mobile.

Check this for an article about relative and absolute paths:
http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Answer (score 2):

As long as headers haven't already been sent, you can use:

```
header('location: successReg.php');
exit;
```

[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp)

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't redirects but only remains on the same page but the registration still works.

Comment: Are you outputting anything else? If there is any `echo`, `print`, `print_r` etc. processed before the `header` command then it won't relocate the page